# "already signed" error when trying to sign openjdk

Tags: java, gradle, codesign, openjfx

We recently switched from oracle jdk to openjdk. When we try to build and sign our application with the javafx-gradle-plugin, we get an error in the signing process.

We already tried to get codesign executed with the force flag (-f) since that does help if we manually sign the problematic file. We did this by adding the additionalJarsignerParameters=["-f"] line in our build.gradle. But that does not seem to affect the codesign execution.

```
    Running [codesign, -s, Developer ID Application: <...>, --prefix, de.<...>.client., -vvvv, /Users/macuser/builds/40a17a50/0/applications/<...>-client/build/jfx/native/<...>.app/Contents/PlugIns/Java.runtime/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jli/libjli.dylib]
    /Users/macuser/builds/40a17a50/0/applications/<...>-client/build/jfx/native/<...>.app/Contents/PlugIns/Java.runtime/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jli/libjli.dylib: is already signed
    java.io.IOException: Exec failed with code 1 command [[codesign, -s, Developer ID Application: <...>, --prefix, de.<...>.client., -vvvv, /Users/macuser/builds/40a17a50/0/applications/<...>-client/build/jfx/native/<...>.app/Contents/PlugIns/Java.runtime/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jli/libjli.dylib] in unspecified directory
    java.io.IOException: Exec failed with code 1 command [[codesign, -s, Developer ID Application: <...>, --prefix, de.<...>.client., -vvvv, /Users/macuser/builds/40a17a50/0/applications/<...>-client/build/jfx/native/<...>.app/Contents/PlugIns/Java.runtime/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jli/libjli.dylib] in unspecified directory
        at com.oracle.tools.packager.IOUtils.exec(IOUtils.java:165)
        at com.oracle.tools.packager.IOUtils.exec(IOUtils.java:138)
        at com.oracle.tools.packager.IOUtils.exec(IOUtils.java:132)
        at com.oracle.tools.packager.mac.MacBaseInstallerBundler.lambda$signAppBundle$18(MacBaseInstallerBundler.java:277)
        at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:184)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$11$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:373)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
        at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
        at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
        at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
        at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:418)
        at com.oracle.tools.packager.mac.MacBaseInstallerBundler.signAppBundle(MacBaseInstallerBundler.java:246)
        at com.oracle.tools.packager.mac.MacBaseInstallerBundler.signAppBundle(MacBaseInstallerBundler.java:219)
        at com.oracle.tools.packager.mac.MacAppBundler.doBundle(MacAppBundler.java:546)
        at com.oracle.tools.packager.mac.MacAppBundler.execute(MacAppBundler.java:1104)
        at de.dynamicfiles.projects.gradle.plugins.javafx.tasks.workers.JfxNativeWorker.jfxnative(JfxNativeWorker.java:348)
        at de.dynamicfiles.projects.gradle.plugins.javafx.tasks.JfxNativeTask.jfxnative(JfxNativeTask.java:32)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:780)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:747)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Answer (score 0):

`jarsigner` is different with `codesign`. You need to add `-f` to your `codesign` cmd, not `jarsigner`.